# Filter an unfiltered table against a whitelist table

Tags: mysql, sql, filtering

**Introduction**

Hi, I'm currently trying to build a filtering system based on MySQL, and I've encountered an issue right now with how to do about it. I've provided two tables in the sample table link below, there's a whitelist table, which contains the whitelisted item, and unsorted table, which is the list of items that will be checked against the whitelist.

PS: The whitelist is changing from time to time

**The problem**

If it were just to match if the three columns match exactly, it'd be a very easy job, however the problem is, **if the columns in the white list is NULL, then that means it's a wildcard** (This behavior can be changed, if someone can provide with better ways to do it), meaning any value in that column is accepted. All three columns must pass before the entry is accepted.

And that's where it gets me stuck =\

**Example**

*Sample Table: http://rextester.com/HMYT21528* or below (same thing)

```
-- unsorted data

create table unsorted (
    ID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    country char(10) null,
    region  char(10) null,
    item    char(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

insert into unsorted(country, region, item) VALUES 

(null, null, "Apple"), (null, "East", "Apple"), (null, "West", "Apple"), 
("US", null, "Apple"), ("US", "East", "Apple"), ("US", "West", "Apple"), 
("CHINA", null, "Apple"), ("CHINA", "East", "Apple"), ("CHINA", "West", "Apple"),

(null, null, "Banana"), (null, "East", "Banana"), (null, "West", "Banana"), 
("US", null, "Banana"), ("US", "East", "Banana"), ("US", "West", "Banana"),
("CHINA", null, "Banana"), ("CHINA", "East", "Banana"), ("CHINA", "West", "Banana"),

(null, null, "Cat"), (null, "East", "Cat"), (null, "West", "Cat"), 
("US", null, "Cat"), ("US", "East", "Cat"), ("US", "West", "Cat"),
("CHINA", null, "Cat"), ("CHINA", "East", "Cat"), ("CHINA", "West", "Cat"),


(null, null, "Donkey"), (null, "East", "Donkey"), (null, "West", "Donkey"),
("US", null, "Donkey"), ("US", "East", "Donkey"), ("US", "West", "Donkey"), 
("CHINA", null, "Donkey"), ("CHINA", "East", "Donkey"), ("CHINA", "West", "Donkey");

-- white list data

create table whitelist (
    country char(10) null,
    region  char(10) null,
    item    char(10) not null
);

insert into whitelist(country, region, item) VALUES 

("US", "West", "Apple"), 
(null, "East", "Banana"), 
("CHINA", null, "Cat"), 
(null, null, "Donkey");
```

There's a column in the white list that looks like this: [ Country: Null, Region: East, Item: Banana ]

What it means is that for any entry in the unsorted list, as long as the item is Banana from East Region, we'll accept it.

Another example would be [ Country: null, Region: null, Item: Donkey ]

What it means is that we'll take any donkey from any country or region, because why not?

**Expected Output**

From the example above, my expected output from the list would be as follows

```
[ 6, US, West Apple ]

[ 11, Null, East, Banana ]
[ 14, US, East, Banana ]
[ 17, China, East, Banana ]

[ 25, China, Null, Cat ]
[ 26, China, East, Cat ]
[ 27, China, West, Cat ]

[ 28, Null, Null, Donkey ]
[ 29, Null, East, Donkey ]
[ 30, Null, West, Donkey ]
[ 31, US, Null, Donkey ]
[ 32, US, East, Donkey ]
[ 33, US, West, Donkey ]
[ 34, China, Null, Donkey ]
[ 35, China, East, Donkey ]
[ 36, China, West, Donkey ]
```

**Edit: to reply to comments**

@Sloan Thrasher

```
SELECT a.*
FROM `unsorted` a
JOIN `whitelist` b
ON IF(b.`country` IS NULL,true,a.`country` = b.`country`) AND
    IF(b.`region` IS NULL,true,a.`region` = b.`region`) AND
    IF(b.`item` IS NULL,true,a.`item` = b.`item`);
```

Since there's no 'id' column on the whitelist, so your where clause would cause an error, also the select should be selecting the unsorted for the result, if I were to select table b, I'd only see filters, instead of the filtered data that I'd like to see.

Comment: Edit your question and put the sample data *in the question*, in a tabular format.

Comment: I don't have that option, and if I were to dump the sample data here, it'd be way too long. Plus the link I provide is a sandbox that you can start trying out directly, so I don't see any reason why putting it here would help =\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do what you are asking:

```
SELECT
    b.*
FROM `unsorted` a
JOIN `whitelist` b
ON IF(b.`country` IS NULL,true,a.`country` = b.`country`) AND
    IF(b.`region` IS NULL,true,a.`region` = b.`region`) AND
    IF(b.`item` IS NULL,true,a.`item` = b.`item`)
WHERE NOT b.`id` IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks, however, there's quite a bit of error in your syntax that I had to fix it first, but this solution works fine once fixed, thanks again :)

Comment: What did you end up with after fixing the syntax errors? Can you edit your question and post the final query that worked?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do what you want with an `exists` subquery:

```
select u.*
from unsorted u
where exists (select 1
              from whitelist wl
              where (wl.country = u.country or wl.country is null) and
                    (wl.region = u.region or wl.region is null) and
                    (wl.item = u.item or wl.item is null)
             );
```

Comment: It returns nothing. =\

Comment: @Willy_Sunny . . . "items" don't equal "countries".  There was a typo in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Ah, missed that, and it works as a charm too, thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to write it:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM unsorted a JOIN whitelist b
 ON a.country <=> COALESCE(b.country, a.country)
AND a.region  <=> COALESCE(b.region, a.region)
AND a.item    <=> COALESCE(b.item, a.item)
```

Similar logic to @SloanThrasher's answer, but it uses some different logical operators.